# CompletableFuture<T> object in Vaadin UI element?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-boot, vaadin

My goal is to call an API in a method that returns a CompletableFuture, such that my vaadin UI does not freeze.

Here's what I've got so far.

The API call:

```
    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<List<Ownership>> getAllOwnerships() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<Ownership[]> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(baseUrl, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(authentication.getHeaders()), Ownership[].class);
        List<Ownership> ownerships = Arrays.asList(responseEntity.getBody());

        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(ownerships);
    }
```

Then in my service layer I have the following:

```
    @Async
    public List<Ownership> getAllOwnerships() {
        if (ownerships.isEmpty()) {
            getOwnershipsFromRemote();
        }

        return ownerships;
    }
```

The list `ownerships` at that point in the class is just an empty ArrayList (not null!). `ownerships` gets populated in `getOwnershipsFromRemote()`:

```
private void getOwnershipsFromRemote() {
        CompletableFuture<List<Ownership>> future = remoteOwnershipData.getAllOwnerships();
        boolean breaker = false;

        while (!breaker) {
            if (future.isDone()) {
                try {
                    this.ownerships = future.get();
                    breaker = true;
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Which calls the method which does the API call as seen at the start.

Now in my Vaadin view I'm trying to do the following:

```
ownershipList = carService.getAllOwnerships();
ownershipListDataProvider = DataProvider.ofCollection(ownershipList);
```

But after the `carService.getAllOwnerships()` call, ownershipList is null, instead of an empty list which I was expecting. I was hoping that this list would then be populated in the `getOwnershipsFromRemote()` call in the service layer, since its populating the same List as is returned by `getAllOwnerships`.

Unfortunately, the null pointer breaks the call to `DataProvider.ofCollection`.

How would I get my vaadin UI element (A grid in this case) to automatically update when the API call finishes? Preferably without doing a while loop to check if the CompletableFuture is done in the vaadin View, since this would block the UI thread, which is what I'm trying to prevent.

For clarity's sake; I'm not trying to get my UI to update automatically when a list inside my view updates (already managed this), but rather I'm looking for an efficient way to get the data from a CompletableFuture into the List that is being watched already by my View, without locking the UI thread with an endless loop.

Comment: Could you check if answer to this question helps with your problem as well?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44352911/updating-data-in-vaadins-grid/44371535#44371535

Comment: Hi @Mika and thanks for your suggestion! Perhaps I should've phrased it clearer but it's not the updating of the UI automatically that's the problem; it's getting the data of a CompletableFuture into a List in my View. My UI is already set to push any changes to a List being observed by a dataprovider. Added an explanation in the main post!

Comment: To be able to update the UI from a background thread, you must activate push and also do the correct synchronized access to the UI elements https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301476/vaadin-7-dont-refresh-ui-after-execution-background-thread-only-if-it-takes-mo